# jQuery generate dynamic table with loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to append this table into Div. but doen't work. There is something wrong with For loop in the middle. What I'm doing wrong here:

```
    var htmlString ="\
                    <table width='97%' height='233px' border='1' class='NewTable'>\
                          <tr>\
                            <th width='43%'>"+currGroupAry[j]+"</th>\
                            <th width='8%'>Points</th>\
                            <th width='49%'>Justification</th>\
                          </tr>\
                          <tr>\
                            <td height='29'>Was willing to frequently share ideas and resources</td>\
                            <td><input id='TotalTEP1' type='text' value='' readonly /></td>\
                            <td>\
                                <table id='gp1' width='100%'>\
                                "for(var i=0; i<=currGroupAry.length; i++){"\
                                    <tr><td style='width:100px;'>"+currGroupAry[j]+"</td><td><textarea style='width:97%; font-size: 14px; background-color: transparent; border:none; resize:none;' cols='10' rows='2' readonly>"+user.comments[j-1]+"</textarea></td></tr>"}"\
                                </table>\
                            </td>\
                          </tr>\</table>"
```

Trying to append this table into Div. but doen't work. There is something wrong with For loop in the middle.

Comment: To provide helpful information, we need full details about your problem. What do you expect to happen, what is happening now, and what have you tried to fix it? Please include error messages and/or descriptions of unexpected behavior.

Comment: There is a for loop in-between the htmlString and looking for a proper syntex to place for loop inside the variable of jQuery.

Comment: There is one main Table and in one <td> I need another table.

Comment: You can't insert the javascript loop inside javascript string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I would do it...given your current code....but then again....its not really how I would do it.....

```
var htmlString ="<table width='97%' height='233px' border='1' class='NewTable'><tr><th width='43%'>"+currGroupAry[j]+"</th><th width='8%'>Points</th><th width='49%'>Justification</th></tr><tr><td height='29'>Was willing to frequently share ideas and resources</td><td><input id='TotalTEP1' type='text' value='' readonly /></td><td><table id='gp1' width='100%'>";

for(var i=0; i<=currGroupAry.length; i++){
htmlString+="<tr><td style='width:100px;'>"+currGroupAry[i]+"</td><td><textarea style='width:97%; font-size: 14px; background-color: transparent; border:none; resize:none;' cols='10' rows='2' readonly>"+user.comments[i-1]+"</textarea></td></tr>";
 }

htmlString+="</table></td></tr></table>";
```

Also....not sure if you want `currGroupAry[j]` or `currGroupAry[i]`, in the loop, you had `j` , but I changed to `i` assuming you want the loop to display relevant info, but change back to `j` if thats what you want.

Comment: KyleK this is exactly what I was looking for. I changed it to j. but getting some error 'user is not defined' under this line: htmlString+="<tr><td style='width:100px;'>"

Comment: Just figured it out. Thanks for the solution KyleK. You rooks!